# Quotients of $c_0\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}}\ell^1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}$ denote the projective tensor product. Let $$\mathcal{S} = \{V\subseteq c_0\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}}\ell^1\textrm{ closed subspace}:  {c_0\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}}\ell^1}/_{V}\textrm{ is isometric to }c_0 \}$$
and $V\sim W \Leftrightarrow V$ and $W$ are isometric.

> **Question:** What is the cardinality of the set of equivalence classes $\mathcal{S}/_\sim$?

Comment: Once you decorate a tensor product, TeX easily forgets that it is a product, and needs to be reminded explicitly with `\mathbin`: compare $c_0 \hat{\otimes}_{\pi} \ell^1$ `c_0 \hat{\otimes}_{\pi} \ell^1` to $c_0 \mathbin{\hat\otimes_\pi} \ell^1$ `c_0 \mathbin{\hat\otimes_\pi} \ell^1`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but $c_0 \mathbin{\hat\otimes_\pi} \ell^1$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}, c_0)$ (see Example 2.6 in "Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces" by R. Ryan). Hence, one has countably many quotients isometric to $c_0$.

Comment: @JohannLangemets Thanks for your kind reply. For any unit norm $x\in\ell^1$, $c_0 \mathbin{\hat\otimes_\pi} x$ is a quotient isometric to $c_0$. So there are at least $\mathfrak{c}$ (continuum) many quotients isometric to $c_0$. However, these are the trivial ones. Perhaps it is clearer from $c_0 \mathbin{\hat\otimes_\pi} \ell^1 = \ell^1(c_0)$ that there can be at most $2^\mathfrak{c}$ many.

Comment: @OnurOktay Yes, you are right. I see now what was the true aim of your question.

Comment: @JohannLangemets I'd like to learn your point of view if you wouldn't mind. 
My initial motivation is to find all weak$^*$ isometric copies of $\ell^1$ in $B(\ell^1)$. Dually, these are precisely given by the quotient maps $c_0 \mathbin{\hat\otimes_\pi} \ell^1\to c_0$. Among those copies, the ones that are subalgebras give us all Banach algebra structures on $\ell^1$ that are compatible with the weak$^*$ topology. On the other side, I think the problem above is interesting in its own right, perhaps more than the original. I'd be happy to tell more, but the space is scarce in the comments.

Comment: @OnurOktay The question is interesting on its own, but unfortunately I don't have anything relevant to add at the moment.